# Active Collab 5 API – HTTP Request

Tags: api, nw.js, activecollab

I am creating an app using NW.js and was wondering if there is a way to access the API via HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not recommend that you make API calls from client side JavaScript (server side is fine). API token should be kept a secret, and never made available to frontend code directly.

What we recommend is to make a backend script that makes API calls using a secret token, and have your client side JavaScript communicate with that backend script, instead of with Active Collab API directly.

If you are using PHP, you can save a lot of time by using Active Collab API SDK:

https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk